# Firefox window.controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection

Tags: javascript, firefox, openlayers

My website works in Chrome, IE, and Safari, but when I load it in Firefox, Firefox complains saying "window.controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection."  This code is in the OpenLayers API (OpenLayers 2, latest version), so I can't change it.  Is there something I can put into my code so that it'll work in Firefox?

Comment: According to [this forum post](https://pyd.io/f/topic/latest-firefox-33-0-2-update-not-working-with-my-pydio-5-2-5-server/) it was broken in FF 33.0 on Windows and Ubuntu, but fixed in 33.1. Have you updated to the latest version?

Comment: I tried but it didn't help.

Comment: This issue still exists for  FireFox 37.0.1. A console error "window.controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection." is thwon up even for a very simple js page

Answer (score 27):

That's because of your medieval firefox extension you have installed. LiveHTTPHeaders in my case.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do you still use LiveHTTPHeaders or have you found one that doesn’t throw this error?

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it "medieval".  It's still a handy extension from time to time - especially whenever I need to follow the entire conversation through a zillion redirects, which is something the Firefox Network tab doesn't do without altering the browser's configuration.  Google Chrome does temporary persistent network tracing better via a nice toggle button on its Network tab.  The best solution in my case is to leave the extension installed and ignore this warning since it's not actually an error.

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to visit `about:config` and set the `loglevel` to `all`

Please refer to all options available in config [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/console)

Comment: please don't post link-only answers.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: 
Add [context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) 
so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. 
[Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)